# Playing local mp4 in browser (chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, video, html5-video, mp4

Just trying out some very basic playing around with HTML5 video, and I can't seem to get the most simple of things working, getting a local mp4 to play in my browser.

I tried an mp4 I had myself but then thought the file might be the problem so now I am literally just trying to play [this video](http://html5doctor.com/demos/video-canvas-magic/video.mp4) in Chrome. I've downloaded it, and I know the path is correct because I've dragged it right into the browser. However, it just displays a black box with the play button greyed out.

What's going on here?

Comment: and if you force refresh (ctrl-f5) does it then load?